# Python3 - mergeSort implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, mergesort

I'm trying to implement mergeSort on my own, but the order of the returned list is still not correct. I must be missing something (especially by the merge step), could someone pls help me what it is?

Here is my code:

```
def merge(left_half, right_half):
    """
    Merge 2 sorted lists.

    :param left_half:       sorted list C
    :param right_half:      sorted list D
    :return:                sorted list B
    """
    i = 0
    j = 0

    B = []

    for item in range(len(left_half) + len(right_half)):

        while i < len(left_half) and j < len(right_half):

            if left_half[i] <= right_half[j]:
                B.insert(item, left_half[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                B.insert(item, right_half[j])
                j += 1

    B += left_half[i:]
    B += right_half[j:]

    print("result: ", B)

    return B


def mergeSort(A):
    """
    Input:      list A of n distinct integers.
    Output:     list with the same integers, sorted from smallest to largest.

    :return:    Output
    """

    # base case
    if len(A) < 2:
        return A

    # divide the list into two
    mid = len(A) // 2
    print(mid)

    left = A[:mid]      # recursively sort first half of A
    right = A[mid:]     # recursively sort second half of A

    x = mergeSort(left)
    y = mergeSort(right)
    return merge(x, y)


print(mergeSort([1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5]))
```

Before the last merge I receive the two lists [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6] correctly, but my final result is [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6].

Comment: Just to be clear, this is for a class, right? Just making sure you're not reimplementing this for real code (where the One True Python sort of `list.sort` and the built-in that wraps it, `sorted`, are the only sorts you should be using). Also, minor nomenclature note: You're working with `list`s (specific return type) or sequences (generalizing to many different input types), not "arrays".

Comment: You can be entirely sure about that, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. This is for algorithm learning purposes only (thinking that I truly understand it if I can implement it). I'm going to modify it for `list`, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration of your for-loop, you entirely traverse one of the lists, but always `insert` at index `0`.

You do not want to `insert` an element, you always want to `append` it. This then makes the for-loop unecessary.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
def merge(left_half, right_half):
    """
    Merge 2 sorted arrays.

    :param left_half:       sorted array C
    :param right_half:      sorted array D
    :return:                sorted array B
    """
    i = 0
    j = 0

    B = []

    while i < len(left_half) and j < len(right_half):
        if left_half[i] <= right_half[j]:
            B.append(left_half[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            B.append(right_half[j])
            j += 1

    B += left_half[i:]
    B += right_half[j:]

    print("result: ", B)

    return B


merge([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
# result:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I was just thinking about the same, that `insert` shouldn't be used. You are absolutely right, thanks for the quick answer! :)